# pandas after groupby and apply function to one of the group how to combine the result back

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a df,you can get it by copy this code:

```
df = """
  ValOption  RB
0       SLA  4
1       AC   5
2       SLA  5
3       PG   5
4       SLA  5
5       PC   4
6       SLA  4

"""
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(df.strip()), sep='\s+')
```

First I group the df:

```
grep=df.groupby('ValOption')
```

then I will have 3 groups:

```
SLA AC PG
```

Now I want to apply 3 different function to these 3 group.

```
def sla_func(df):
  return df['RB']*3+df['RB']

def ac_func(df):
  return df['RB']/4*df['RB']+1

def pg_func(df):
  return df['RB']-5
```

And then the result will the value of a new column named group_v.

The output should looks like:

```
ValOption   RB  group_y
0   SLA    4    16
1   AC     5    7.25
2   SLA    5    20
3   PG     5    0
4   SLA    5    20
5   AC     4    5
6   SLA    4    16
```

Since in the real business logic there are tens of thousands  rows ,so I think if I use group it maybe faster.

I tried use:

```
grp=df.groupby(['ValOption'])
sla=grp.get_group(('SLA').apply(sla(df))
ac=grp.get_group(('AC').apply(ac(df))
pg=grp.get_group(('PG').apply(pg(df))
```

But now work...any friend can help?

**Notice in my real business, the function is extremely complicated ,I need a common way to solve that, the reason why I want to try groupby is because speed is very important to me ,thank you so much!**

Comment: In your actual use case are the functions more complex than simply multiplying each group by different values?

Comment: yes,yes,very very complicated!extramly complicated!

Comment: You have 4 groups. typo?

Comment: Okay. You might consider updating your shown functions to be non-trivial, because this is not clear in the question itself which leads to answers like the one you recieved.

Answer (score 0):

No need for `groupby`, just map `ValOption` to different factors and then multiply it with `RB`:

```
df['group_y'] = df.ValOption.map({'SLA': 3, 'AC': 4, 'PG': 5}) * df.RB

df    
  ValOption  RB  group_y
0       SLA   4       12
1        AC   5       20
2       SLA   5       15
3        PG   5       25
4       SLA   5       15
5        AC   4       16
6       SLA   4       12
```

If the function is complex, you can decide which function to invoke based on `g.name` in `groupby.apply`:

```
group_funcs = {'SLA': sla, 'AC': ac, 'PG': pg}
df['group_y'] = df.groupby('ValOption', group_keys=False).apply(lambda g: group_funcs[g.name](g))

df
  ValOption  RB  group_y
0       SLA   4       12
1        AC   5       20
2       SLA   5       15
3        PG   5       25
4       SLA   5       15
5        AC   4       16
6       SLA   4       12
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply,but do you have a common way for complicated function,this function is very simple but in real world the function will be very complicated

Comment: @William in that case, you can leverage `g.name` to check the group variable value in each group and decide which function to invoke in `apply`. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can do with .apply and then customize the function you want to apply:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from io import StringIO

def col_group_y(row):
    if row['ValOption']=='SLA':
        return row['RB']*3
    elif row['ValOption']=='AC':
        return row['RB']*4
    elif row['ValOption']=='PG':
        return row['RB']*5
    else:
        return row['RB']



df = """
  ValOption  RB
0       SLA  4
1       AC   5
2       SLA  5
3       PG   5
4       SLA  5
5       PC   4
6       SLA  4

"""
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(df.strip()), sep='\s+')
df['group_y']=df.apply(col_group_y,axis=1)
print(df)
```

result

```
  ValOption  RB  group_y
0       SLA   4       12
1        AC   5       20
2       SLA   5       15
3        PG   5       25
4       SLA   5       15
5        PC   4        4
6       SLA   4       12
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your relpy,but df.apply is the lowest way to that.I need a fast way.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this solution:

```
df = """
  ValOption  RB
0       SLA  4
1       AC   5
2       SLA  5
3       PG   5
4       SLA  5
5       PC   4
6       SLA  4

"""
def sla_func(df):
  return df['RB']*3+df['RB']

def ac_func(df):
  return df['RB']/4*df['RB']+1

def pg_func(df):
  return df['RB']-5



df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(df.strip()), sep='\s+')


col         = 'ValOption'
conditions  = [ df[col] =='SLA', df[col] =='AC', df[col] =='PG' ]
choices     = [ sla_func(df), ac_func(df), pg_func(df) ]
    
df["group_y"] = np.select(conditions, choices, default=np.nan)

print(df)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply ,this is most way I used ,but it dose not solve my issue, it is kind of slow in this case.